# How can I set up a Java Server with specific IP and Port with a normal Webhosting Package?

Tags: java, sockets, ip, port, web-hosting

I want to create a Java Webserver with some existing Web Hosting/Space with IP/Port so that I can test Socket Programming Features. I already have a Webhosting Package at https://alfahosting.de/ Is it possible to do socket programming with this webhosting package? If it is not possible to do Socket programming with this webhosting package. How is it possible? Are their special webhosting packages that support socket programming with an own IP and Port?

I also would like to know if their is a tutorial how to set up a java webserver socket in a web hosting package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most webhosting packages only allow to host static HTML pages and CGI (PHP, Perl) scripts.
Some provide JSP and JSF support but those are more expensive than regular webhosters.

If you want to code your own webserver/socket applications in java you need a root server package (I, for example, use a vServer for €12,99/month)

On such server you have direct root access to the machine, where you can install any software you want - so you just have to install the java runtime engine of your choice and you are good to go (assuming the server's firewall is set correctly) - with a dedicated IP address you can directly connect to your servers java programs.